How to extract the access_token value in JMETER when it is not directly present in the key/value pair
self.__next_f.push([
1,
"abcd:T443,eyJraWQiOiMM3N:["$","$L15",null,{"idToken":"$16","accessToken":"$17","error":null}]\n"
])
Here accessToken starts is "eyJraWQiOiMM3N"
Have tried using JSON extractor :$.accessToken,but it is not working

You cannot use JSON Extractor because it's a part of JavaScript code (plain text)
The easiest would be using Boundary Extractor, all you need to do is to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between:

If you want to achieve the same with the Regular Expression Extractor - go for something like abcd:T443,(.+?)::

